# translate a CPTXYPlotSpace in ios using coreplot

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, core-plot

I am new to core-plot and am a bit stuck. I have 2 plots in a single view. I am trying to make it so if the user drags or scales one of them, the other also gets dragged/scaled. The first plot is calling my CPTPlotSpaceDelegate in the event of a scale or drag using

-(BOOL)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space shouldScaleBy:(CGFloat)interactionScale aboutPoint:(CGPoint)interactionPoint

and

-(CGPoint)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space willDisplaceBy:(CGPoint)proposedDisplacementVector

respectively.

I am just unsure how to get my second plot to translate/scale in conjunction with these events. Does anyone have any thoughts on how this might be approached?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you can use the same plot space for both plots, do that. In that case, they'll move together with no additional effort on your part.